# A DSP SDK for VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sdk, signal-processing, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a project that requires real time tracking of vocal formants using Digital Signal Processing of live mic input.

My environment is Microsoft VC++ 2010 Express, the target platform is Windows. It seems extremely difficult to find a good DSP SDK that isn't built to develop for unix/linux or depend on cygwin for windows support. Most of the DSP stuff I was able to find for windows are pipe and box environments, where you make boxes that stand for DSP functions and pipe around live audio between them to make some result.

Is there either a good DSP SDK that works well with MSVC++ 2010 for windows development?

Answer (score 0):

While there aren't many good dedicated DSP Libraries and SDK's available for C++ on Windows, there are alternatives that are capable of DSP and accessible through C++ on windows.

Matlab apparently has an API for controlling an instance via C++, however matlab is extremely expensive for this application. I've found evidence that Octave, the free open source matlab compatible environment, has some C++ api for direct access to it's functions. However I am having trouble finding exactly where this API is hidden, but I'll spawn another question considering that if I don't find some answers among the materials available to me.

Comment: The Octave library is not very friendly when taken out from it's Octave brand cygwin gcc environment shelter. Further research leads me to the conclusion that there are no good signal processing libraries out there. This is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intel's IPP for Signal Processing.

There are some Intel's DSP libraries for windows within their set of so called "Integrated Performance Primitives", IPP

: https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-ipp-for-windows. They are advertising that they support Windows, Linux and MacOS as well.

Search for document Architecture Developer Reference. Volume 1. Signal and Data Processing for a list of already available functions.

I believe that there is a possibility that the libraries are free, except for encryption portion of it.